# Octave: function doesn't return expected value?

Tags: syntax, octave

This code is a programming assignment for Andrew Ng's machine learning course.

The function is expecting a row vector `[J grad]`. The code computes `J` (albeit wrongly, but that's not the issue here), and I put in a dummy value for `grad` (because I haven't written the code to compute it yet). When I run the code, it only outputs `ans` as a scalar with the value of `J`. Where did `grad` go?

```
function [J grad] = nnCostFunction(nn_params, ...
                               input_layer_size, ...
                               hidden_layer_size, ...
                               num_labels, ...
                               X, y, lambda)
%NNCOSTFUNCTION Implements the neural network cost function for a two layer
%neural network which performs classification
%   [J grad] = NNCOSTFUNCTON(nn_params, hidden_layer_size, num_labels, ...
%   X, y, lambda) computes the cost and gradient of the neural network. The
%   parameters for the neural network are "unrolled" into the vector
%   nn_params and need to be converted back into the weight matrices. 
% 
%   The returned parameter grad should be a "unrolled" vector of the
%   partial derivatives of the neural network.
%

% Reshape nn_params back into the parameters Theta1 and Theta2, the weight matrices
% for our 2 layer neural network
Theta1 = reshape(nn_params(1:hidden_layer_size * (input_layer_size + 1)), ...
                 hidden_layer_size, (input_layer_size + 1));

Theta2 = reshape(nn_params((1 + (hidden_layer_size * (input_layer_size + 1))):end), ...
                 num_labels, (hidden_layer_size + 1));

% Setup some useful variables
m = size(X, 1);

% You need to return the following variables correctly 
J = 0;
Theta1_grad = zeros(size(Theta1));
Theta2_grad = zeros(size(Theta2));

% ====================== YOUR CODE HERE ======================
% Instructions: You should complete the code by working through the
%               following parts.
%
% Part 1: Feedforward the neural network and return the cost in the
%         variable J. After implementing Part 1, you can verify that your
%         cost function computation is correct by verifying the cost
%         computed in ex4.m
%
% Part 2: Implement the backpropagation algorithm to compute the gradients
%         Theta1_grad and Theta2_grad. You should return the partial derivatives of
%         the cost function with respect to Theta1 and Theta2 in Theta1_grad and
%         Theta2_grad, respectively. After implementing Part 2, you can check
%         that your implementation is correct by running checkNNGradients
%
%         Note: The vector y passed into the function is a vector of labels
%               containing values from 1..K. You need to map this vector into a 
%               binary vector of 1's and 0's to be used with the neural network
%               cost function.
%
%         Hint: We recommend implementing backpropagation using a for-loop
%               over the training examples if you are implementing it for the 
%               first time.
%
% Part 3: Implement regularization with the cost function and gradients.
%
%         Hint: You can implement this around the code for
%               backpropagation. That is, you can compute the gradients for
%               the regularization separately and then add them to Theta1_grad
%               and Theta2_grad from Part 2.
%

% PART 1

a1 = [ones(m,1) X]; % set a1 to equal X and add column of 1's

z2 = a1 * Theta1'; % matrix times matrix [5000*401 * 401*25 = 5000*25]
a2 = [ones(m,1),sigmoid(z2)]; % sigmoid function on matrix [5000*26]
z3 = a2 * Theta2'; % matrix times matrix [5000*26 * 26*10 = 5000 * 10]
hox = sigmoid(z3); % sigmoid function on matrix [5000*10]

for k = 1:num_labels

    yk = y == k; % using the correct column vector y each loop
    J = J + sum(-yk.*log(hox(:,k)) - (1-yk).*log(1-hox(:,k)));

end

J = 1/m * J;   

% -------------------------------------------------------------

% =========================================================================

% Unroll gradients
% grad = [Theta1_grad(:) ; Theta2_grad(:)];
grad = 6.6735;

end
```

Comment: you don't show how you call your function. Make sure to have 2 outputs: `[foo bar] = nnCostFunction (...)`

Comment: I call my function like this: nnCostFunction(nn_params, input_layer_size, hidden_layer_size, num_labels, X, y, lambda). All of the parameters are supplied with values by the course, so I plop them in. And what do you mean by having two outputs? While calling, in the function definition, in the body of the function, ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specified in your function declaration that the function can simultaneously return more than one output value:

```matlab
function [J grad] = nnCostFunction(nn_params, ...   % etc
```

You can capture both outputs if you 'request' them by assigning to a matrix of variables instead of a single variable:

```matlab
[a, b] = nnCostFunction(input1, input2, etc)
```

If you don't do this, you're essentially 'requesting' only the first of the returned variables:

```matlab
a = nnCostFunction(input1, input2, etc)  % output 'b' is discarded.
```

If you don't specify a variable to assign to at all, octave by default assigns to the 'default' variable `ans`. So it's essentially equivalent to doing

```matlab
ans = nnCostFunction(input1, input2, etc)  % output 'b' is discarded.
```

See the documentation for the `find` function (i.e. type `help find` in your octave terminal) to see an example of such a function.

---

PS. If you only wanted the *second* output and did not want to 'waste' a variable name for the first one, you can do this by specifying `~` as the first output, e.g.:

```matlab
[~, b] = nnCostFunction(input1, input2, etc)  % output 'a' is discarded
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer